# Angular passing data to the back-end service using find method

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I've tried checking the data and console logging it and the data exist , but when I check the request from the back-end it was not passed . Is this how we pass data to the back-end service in angular ? or I have issue with my code ? Thanks.

## Code

```
checkExistingFeedbackRequest(formGroup: FormGroup, respondents: Identity[]): Observable<FeedbackRequest[]> {
  
    let request = formGroup.value

    const data = respondents
      .map(respondent => cleanUpFeedbackRequestAssociations({
        ...request,
        respondent,
        respondentId: respondent.id
      }) as FeedbackRequest);
    
    console.log("data:" , data)

    return from(this.service.find<FeedbackRequest>(data)
      .pipe(
        map((result) => result.data)
      );
  }
```

Comment: Hello Mark, not sure if I completely understand your question. Are you asking how you can send an http request to the backend using Angular?

Comment: yeah2 , like using a find property @saglamcem ,

Comment: For future references - if the data you'd like to "find" is to be received from the backend by a request, "fetch" is a better word. Find makes (at least me) think that you iterate through a list and find an item, so it's a little misleading. :)

Comment: To answer your question, you should be able to find your answer in the official Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http it pretty much contains any scenario you might need. :)